# Rescue Tip: Wrong library file installation damaged Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-18.04, disaster-recovery, linode

There was an old Ubuntu 14.04 linode.com instance which I attempted to upgrade to 18.04. Some Dependencies where somehow not upgraded anyway.

So I attempted to install corresponding deb file from Ubuntu server (as it was not in repo)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg : Breaks: libdpkg-perl (< 1.18.11) but 1.18.4ubuntu1 is to be installed
        Breaks: libdpkg-perl:i386 (< 1.18.11)
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.25) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27)
```

I accidentally installed wrong version of libc6 which result to damage the instance.

```
root@myself:~# dpkg -i libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading libc6:amd64 from 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 to 2.27-3ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 110607 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
/usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Now I cannot access ssh

Login via Lish Gateway(Linode SH), I get the following message and it doesn't accept any login.

```
 * Stopping flush early job output to logs                               [ OK ]
 * Starting SystemD login management service                             [ OK ]
 * Starting system logging daemon                                        [ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart                            [ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart                              [ OK ]
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices                                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation                                  [ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon                 [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting configure virtual network devices                            [ OK ]
 * Starting MySQL Server                                                 [fail]
 * Restoring resolver state...                                           [ OK ]
 * Stopping MySQL Server                                                 [ OK ]                                                                         
 *                                                                             
 * The apache2 configtest failed.                                              
Output of config test was:                                                     
/usr/sbin/apache2: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
Action 'configtest' failed.                                                    
The Apache error log may have more information.                                
 * Stopping System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
                                                                               
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS nmd2 ttyS0                                             
                                                                               
nmd2 login:                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So attempting a rescue mode is the only option. It seems libcrypt dependency is causing the error.

How to solve this in rescue mode. Any advice please.

Comment: Create a new instance and move your data.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I need to recover mysql databse. Is it possible via any other means please.

Comment: Of course you need to recover the database. So create the new instance and move the data.